# Need Schengen visa with UK work permit and indian passport

Tags: schengen

I have UK work permit visa till June 2 2014. I am planning to go to Europe trip in March. From the enquiry I came to know that to apply Schengen my UK visa should be valid for 90 days from the end date of Schengen visa. Can I get a Schengen visa or not?

Comment: If you need to have your UK visa valid for 90 days from the end of your Schengen visa, then you should be able to get the Schengen visa ending on March 4 2014.

Comment: Are the dates wrong?

Comment: Isn't June 2 2014 already in the past? Are you sure about the dates on your visa?